# Web Api to Signalr Azure token not working

Tags: signalr, asp.net-web-api2, owin, azure-active-directory

I have a Asp.Net Web Api (Api1) that needs to send a message to a Signalr Realtime Api (Api2). I am trying to use Azure AD bearer tokens to authenticate. The client for Api1 is a JavaScript client that uses ADAL.js to get a token from Azure.

```
    var authContext = new AuthenticationContext({    
            tenant: tenantId,
            clientId: jsclientId,
            postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location.origin,
            cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
            endpoints: {
                api1Url: api1ResourceUri
            }
    });

    authContext.acquireToken(jsclientId, function (error, token) {
        if (error || !token) {
            authContext.clearCache();
            authContext.login();
        } 
    });
```

The JS client attaches this token in the Authorization header to all Api calls to Api1. In Api1 I am using the following code to get an access token from Azure AD.

```
var userAssertion = new UserAssertion(bootstrapContext.Token, "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer", userName);

var result = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(api2ResourceId,  new ClientCredential(api1clientId, api1clientSecret), userAssertion);
```

I am attaching this access token to the request as an authorization header "Bearer tokenvalue". In the Signalr Hub Owin Startup class I have the following code.

```
app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
{
    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
            ValidAudiences = api1Audiences,
            SaveSigninToken = true
    },
    Tenant = configSection.TenantId
});
```

While the ClaimsIdentity on the hub is showing as authenticated, the user's identity is not being set. identity.name is null. It looks like the users identity is not being passed on to the Signalr hub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting no User Identity in your API because you are authenticating to it as an application, not as a user.

The acquireTokenAsync overload that only takes in resource and ClientCredentials is for the Client Credentials flow (a.k.a App-only flow).

What you need to do is to use the On-behalf-of flow to swap the token you got for API1 for a token for API2.

So in **API1's** Startup.Auth, TokenValidation parameters, set Save SigninToken to true like so:

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
  OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
  {
      // ...
      TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
      {
        SaveSigninToken = true
      },
      // ...
  });
```

And then wherever you want to call your API2, do as follows:

```
ClientCredential clientCred = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
var bootstrapContext = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identities.First().BootstrapContext as System.IdentityModel.Tokens.BootstrapContext;
string userName = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Upn) != null ? ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Upn).Value : ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email).Value;
string userAccessToken = bootstrapContext.Token;
UserAssertion userAssertion = new UserAssertion(bootstrapContext.Token, "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer", userName);

result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(api2ResourceId, clientCred, userAssertion);
```

See it in the sample: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-onbehalfof, specificaly the ToDoService's Startup.Auth.cs and TodoListController.cs.

**NOTE**: This sample is for native app + web api, you're adapting it for web app + web api.

**Edit** - Make sure your JS code is requesting a token for your API1 by specifying API1 in the JS acquireToken call like so:

```
var authContext = new AuthenticationContext({    
        tenant: tenantId,
        clientId: jsclientId,
        postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location.origin,
        cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
        endpoints: {
            api1Url: api1ResourceUri
        }
});

authContext.acquireToken(api1clientId, function (error, token) {
    if (error || !token) {
        authContext.clearCache();
        authContext.login();
    } 
});
```

Comment: My bad, that should be api2ResourceId, fixed it.

Comment: I updated AcquireTokenAsync and UserAssertion as mentioned. Now I get an error "Assertion audience claim does not match the required value". It says that audience expected is that of Api1 but that the audience is that of the javascript client that calls Api1. I have updated the question to show the JS client code as well.

Comment: You are still missing the UserAssertion in the AcquireContext call.

Comment: Sorry I just didnt update the question completely. I am passing the userAssertion in the AcqureToken call.

Comment: Sounds like you have 3 Azure AD applications then. One for the JS client, one for API 1 and one for API 2. Can you update your question such that all  resources, and clientIDs identify which app they belong to? i.e. clientIdJsClient, resourceUriApi1, etc...

Comment: Regardless, you should have the following:
JS uses - jsAppClientId, api1ResourceId
API1 uses - api1ClientId, api2ResourceId

Comment: I have updated the question to reflect the client ids and uri's for each of the 3 apps.

Comment: I still get the error "Assertion audience claim does not match the required value". It says that audience expected is that of Api1 but that the audience is that of the javascript client that calls Api1.

Comment: Can you also add the snippet where you call acquireToken in your SPA? What are you passing as the resource?

Comment: I've added the acquireToken method from the JS app.

Comment: So in your JS app, you're requesting a token for the JS app and not for API1, which is why API1 is unable to swap it out for API2 and you get that "Assertion audience claim does not match the required value". You need to make sure you ask for a toke for API1. I've updated my answer with this info.